Cookie handling in SvelteKit 5 + .NET Core
I'm currently building an app with .NET Core in the backend and SvelteKit 5 in the front with server-side loading (multiple +layout.server.ts scripts, loading various data "layers"). Both backend and frontend calls happen on the same subdomain, choreographed by an Nginx reverse proxy (the SvelteKit installation uses Vite and the Node adapter).
Authentication is OAuth 2.0 (technically 2.1 compliant) handled in the backend automagically by Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google, plus Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies for persistence. For API calls from the frontend, the backend publishes an npm library based on @hey-api/openapi-ts (an Axios client).
As long as I treat this project as a vanilla Svelte SPA, everything works fine because cookies flow naturally between my server and the browser both ways.
My problems started when I decided to optimize the app by taking advantage of SvelteKit 5's server-side data loading. In this setup, the browser receives .AspNetCore cookies directly from my .NET Core backend (which needs to get hit because it handles OAuth+PKCSE), then the browser passes the cookies via HTTP(S) to the SvelteKit server-side script, which has to propagate them to the backend. I ended up with a rather fragile implementation in my +layout.server.ts scripts along these lines:
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';
import { client, getFoo } from 'My.Library';
import { PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE } from '$env/static/public';

client.setConfig({ baseURL: PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE, headers: {} });

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async (event) => {
    const options = {
        headers: {
            Cookie: event.request.headers.get('cookie')
        }
    };
    
    const myResponse = await getFoo(options);

    return {
        foo: myResponse.data
    };
};

This is provably a bad approach, but it originally worked, and it's the least bad compromise I could find.
The real problems really came alive when I started layering these +layout.server.ts scripts across the routes, and my .NET backend started to push updates to the .AspNetCore cookies upstream: my upstream client was now the SvelteKit server-side code. I could attempt to keep on patching my bad solution by propagating the cookies up to the browser, but now I had to deal with potentially several versions of the same cookie received at various levels across the route. If that's not an obvious fail, I don't know what is.
I knew for a while now I've been fighting the framework; now I finally accept defeat. What's the proper way to do this?
